# text-field data is erased when view loaded successfully

Tags: ios, swift, segue

There are three scene

```
adminSignup(Parent) --> It has two text field country and city
countrySelectorView(Child of adminSignup) --> It has picker view to select country
citySelectorView(Child of adminSignup) --> It has picker view to select city
```

When country text-field is clicked of adminSignup then countrySelectorView scene is called and user will select the country and then it will go back to adminSignup scene and country value will be passed to adminSignup.

But when city text-field is clicked then countrySelectorView scene is called and user will select the country and then it will go back to adminSignup scene and country value will be passed to adminSignup and the value of country text-field is erased.

Below is the code of adminSignUp

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let passedCityValue = cityValue {
        cityTextFeild.text = passedCityValue
    }
    if let currentCountryValue = countryValue {
       countryTextFeild.text = currentCountryValue
    }
}
```

Below is the code of countrySelectorView

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard  let instanceOfAdminSignUp = segue.destination as? adminSignUp else {    return    }
    instanceOfAdminSignUp.countryValue = countryValue
}
```

Below is the code of citySelectorView

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let instanceOfAdminSignUp = segue.destination as? adminSignUp else { return }
    instanceOfAdminSignUp.cityValue = cityValue
}
```

Comment: You need to put relevant code *in your question*, but my guess is that you keep moving forward to new instances of the various view controllers, rather than moving backward to the original one.  But really, there is no need for additional view controllers.  Those two pickers should be set up as the input accessory views for the relevant text fields.

Comment: Please show us your implementation code. Then only we will be able to help you out @Quershi

Comment: @Paulw i was not able to format the code so i have given the GitHub Link at the end of question. Please can you share some stuff for picker view input accessory so that i can understand more better about it.

Comment: @Rizwan please check [link](https://github.com/jasham/Razers/tree/develop/saloonMaster/Admin/Controller)

Comment: A Github link is basically useless. It is up to you to put the effort in to make the question useful and create an MCVE. Stackoverflow is not a code writing or code debugging service. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RoboticCat please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below mentioned steps

1- **adminSignup View Controller**:

Use Delegate Design Pattern for Communication between 2 ViewControllers

```
protocol AdminSignUPDelegate: class {
   func cityValuePicked(value: String)
   func countryValuePicked(value: String)
}

extension adminSignUp: AdminSignUPDelegate {

    func cityValuePicked(value: String) {
         cityTextFeild.text = value
    }
    func countryValuePicked(value: String) {
        countryTextFeild.text = value
    }

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? countrySelectorController {
        destinationViewController.delegate = self
    }
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? citySelectorController {
        destinationViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

2- City Selection ViewController

```
// Property
var delegate: AdminSignUPDelegate?

@IBAction func btnOKPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.cityValuePicked(value: cityValue)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

3- Country Selection ViewController

```
    // Property
var delegate: AdminSignUPDelegate?

@IBAction func btnOKPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.countryValuePicked(value: countryValue)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Note**: Remove Segue from Country & City View Controller to The Parent

Any how you can download the working example of your code from here as well

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lA5ewSvw6KGyLW4XKQm10wSDE9dl_2PB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @Waqas I have tried this but not working.

Comment: Thanks @Waqas I got the output as expected. It was very helpful.